# Updating Field in Another List when creating new Item in other List

Tags: updatelistitems

I'm new to SharePoint so maybe the question is stupid.
My Problem is, that I have Lists with Publications and Projects. A Publication requires an Project.
When I create an Publication I want that these Publication get automatically linked in the Project Item which is selected as Project for the Publication.
If I open the Project the Publication should be shown and linked for the user.

But I don't find any way to build an Filter or something else.

Thanks for any help or resources you can share.

PS: We are using SharePoint 2013

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This could also be done either by using an event receiver or an Custom Workflow using SharePoint Designer. This is to do it automatically.

Both of these options requires some experience of SharePoint and in the case of an event receiver some experience of developing for SharePoint and writing custom code and deploying it to the SharePoint 2013 Farm.

You can read more about event receivers here. [How to: Create an event receiver](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/sharepoint/how-to-create-an-event-receiver)

You can read more about creating custom workflows here. [Creating a workflow by using SharePoint Designer 2013 and the SharePoint Workflow platform](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/general-development/creating-a-workflow-by-using-sharepoint-designer-and-the-sharepoint-wo)

Answer (score 0):

Just to clarification:

1. You have 2 separate lists- Projects and Publications
2. In both you have lookup fields (Projects -> Publications and back)
3. If you set value of lookup in one list, you want SharePoint
   will make changes in sibling list ?

If yes - you can install SharePoint Designer and create workflow process, that will update field in sibling list when publication will created.